# AWS Server Cronjob not working

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron

I have configured one cronjob AWS server but it is not working.

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null https://example.com/cron
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the same with **curl**.  Run "which curl" to get its location.

For instance, if it's in **/usr/bin/curl**:

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -o /dev/null https://example.com/cron
```